# Wordpress gives 404 error with a custom query

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

There are lots of questions similar to this, but none seem to be a fix for me sadly...

I am trying to filter results by using a custom query within Wordpress, via the Wordpress' `query_vars`, however [I instead get a 404 error](http://gradehack.com/?subject=15). This error only occurs when the query I enter in the URL is one of those that I've added to the custom query functions.php function.

### functions.php

```
function create_posttype_modules() {

    register_post_type( 'modules',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Modules' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Module' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'modules'),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'category' ),
            'supports' => array('title'),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype_modules' );


function add_my_var($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'subject';
    $public_query_vars[] .= 'orderselected';
    return $public_query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_my_var');
```

### Form excerpt used on page

```
    <?php

echo '<form id="order" action="' . esc_url( home_url( "/" ) ) . '" method="get">';
?>
  <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['subject']);?>">
  <select name="orderselected" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
    <option value="name" <?php echo get_query_var('orderselected') == 'none' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Select</option>
    <option value="name" <?php echo get_query_var('orderselected') == 'name' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Name</option>
    <option value="mean" <?php echo get_query_var('orderselected') == 'mean' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Mean grade</option>
    <option value="first" <?php echo get_query_var('orderselected') == 'first' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>1st %</option>
    <option value="twoone" <?php echo get_query_var('orderselected') == 'twoone' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>2:1 %</option>
    <option value="twotwo" <?php echo get_query_var('orderselected') == 'twotwo' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>2:2 %</option>
    <option value="third" <?php echo get_query_var('orderselected') == 'third' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>3rd %</option>
    <option value="fail" <?php echo get_query_var('orderselected') == 'fail' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Fail %</option>
  </select>

    <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="View" />
    </noscript>
</form>
```

### I've had this working on a sub-page

I have had this working on a sub-page (with only other minor difference being I changed the `cat` query to `subject`) [within a page here](http://maxbeech.com/exeterentrepreneurs/gradehack/?orderselected=&cat=17#). But having transferred WP and made the gradehack page the homepage, the problem has arisen.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: where you apply the filter? Can you please add that code?

Comment: Many thanks for your help @ShivendraSingh - have added

Comment: A 404 means file not found, a query error or script error of any type should never produce this. Are you sure you have your file permissions correct on the remote server after uploading your files?

Comment: Will double check them, thanks @geoffrey. Forgot to say though that the 404 error ONLY occurs when the query is one of those added to the functions.php function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in case anyone else comes across this, turns out I needed to set "Your homepage displays" in Settings > Reading to "Your latest posts", rather than display the page as a static page.